# Unexpected token: int, processing 2.21

Tags: syntax, int, processing, token

I'm working with processing 2.2.1, and I am 90% sure that this is syntactically correct. I keep getting an error explaining that it is incorrect with an "unexpected token: int".

```java
void growEllipse(int ellipseHW){
    if(int i = 0; i != width*2; i++){
       ellipseHW = ellipseHW++;
  }
```

I have tried moving the int to within the function, like so (check below) but then I get an error saying that it is "expecting RPAREN, found ';'".

```java
void growEllipse(int ellipseHW){
  int i;
  if(i = 0; i != width*2; i++){
    ellipseHW = ellipseHW++;
  }
}
```

This is rather frustrating because it seems syntactically correct.
Can anybody help me figure it out?

Comment: Once you are happy with an answer and you are sure it is what you need don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I kept getting told I couldn't accept for x amount of time and kind of forgot to get back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a **for loop**, not an **if statement**:

```java
for(int i = 0; i != width*2; i++){
  ellipseHW = ellipseHW++;
}
```

More info on the for loop can be found in [the Processing reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/for.html).

Comment: ahhhh.... dammit. Thanks. I guess that's what happens when you stay up working on programming classes for three days. Thanks. That was a rookie mistake.

Comment: @pacificfrost No problem. Happens to the best of us. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a 'for' statement instead of an 'if' statement.

Comment: Thanks! Such a rookie mistake T_T